# Merge highlighting with rest of response in SOLR

Tags: solr, solrj

When I enable highlighting in SOLR I get all most of the output under `response`, but the highlighting under `highlighting` - as expected. Is this possible to change? Is it possible to get the excerpt together with the rest of the hit?
I have seen other answers here that suggest post-processing, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266825/3246362, but a lot has happened since then. Are better options available?

Comment: A lot has happened since then but unfortunately nothing has happened regarding this, AFAIK.

Comment: How do you want highlighting together with the rest of the hit? As a pre-named field?

Comment: @MatsLindh, why not? That is what I did in my post-processing.

Comment: I'm not asking why not, I'm asking what you want the result to be. I can see that there's value in having a single structure with all information about the document, including the highlighting information.

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of words. I think would make a lot of sense. I named it "excerpt".